# Apache Server no permission to open php page

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to open a index.php on my apache server and my browser says it doesn't have permission to open the page (it doesn't show the typical error 403, it seems to be a different error). The interesting thing is, it does allow to show exactly one file (phpinfo.php), but no other php (the html files work just fine). The permissions of all the files in my html folder are the same and I am running out of ideas.

The apache error.log doesn't show any errors while trying to connect to the page

Update: It seems to make a difference if I create the file with nano directly on the server via ssh or uploading them via ftp. With nano they show with ftp they don't.

My ls -la from /var/www/html:

```
    total 64
drwxrwxr-- 4 pi       www-data  4096 May 26 09:24 .
drwxr-s--- 3 www-data www-data  4096 May 26 09:18 ..
-rwxrwxr-- 1 pi       www-data   738 May 26 08:27 changeState.php
-rwxrwxr-- 1 pi       www-data    96 May 26 08:27 echoContact.php
drwxrwxr-- 2 pi       www-data  4096 May 26 08:27 img
-rwxrwxr-- 1 pi       www-data   671 May 26 08:27 index_2.htm
-rwxrwxr-- 1 pi       www-data 11473 May 26 08:27 index.html
-rwxrwxr-- 1 pi       www-data  1709 May 26 09:24 index.php
drwxrwxr-- 2 pi       www-data  4096 May 26 08:27 json
-rwxrwxr-- 1 pi       www-data    38 May 26 09:24 phpinfo.php
-rwxrwxr-- 1 pi       www-data   851 May 26 08:27 remove.php
-rwxrwxr-- 1 pi       www-data  1710 May 26 09:20 test.php
-rwxrwxr-- 1 pi       www-data   583 May 26 08:27 toggleTodo.php
-rwxrwxr-- 1 pi       www-data  3709 May 26 08:27 write.php
```

Comment: _“but no other”_ - including the .htm(l) files, or the PHP scripts only? If the latter, then it could perhaps be some sort of access control implemented _within_ those scripts? (And if “all of them”, including the static types, then maybe URL rewriting is in play, and rewriting those requests to a script that performs such a check first?) Impossible to tell for sure, with this little info.

Comment: Oh sorry for the somewhat misleading wording. The html files do show just fine, its just the php pages

Comment: And I have an update: It seems to make a difference whether I create the file with nano directly on the server via ssh or uploading them via ftp. With nano they show with ftp they don't.